# About a sequence with a simple property.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

I want to use 1-n to generate a sequence S whose length is 2*n. Each number from 1-n will appear exactly twice. The sequence should satisfy the following property: if S[i] = S[j] = k, i < j, j-i should be k. For example: when n=4, a target sequence is 11423243.

Question 1: Prove: only when n=4m or 4m+1, m >= 1, this kind of sequence exists.

Question 2: Given n, how to generate thus a sequence quickly?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). If this is HW, it should be tagged as such (people will still help). Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share those as it helps responders? Regards

Comment: I think these are called Skolem sequences.